# Change text for a unit in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am using [siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package.

When I type `\SI{60}{\second}`, the output will be `60 s`.

How can I change the appearing text in the output to be `60 sec`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\DeclareSIUnit` writes over old definitions with impunity, so you can use the following.  Note you will no longer be following the SI standards.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\second}{sec}

\begin{document}

\SI{60}{\second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for `\DeclareSIUnit{\byte}{o}` (with `binary-units` package option).  Any idea why ?